# Typescript type inference with mapped types does not work correctly

Tags: typescript, types, casting

I'm trying to use TypeScript to provide type safety in my application.

I have a few types with required "value" fields. They also have a "type" property that I use for type narrowing.
Then I created a union type of this types. I can check what is inside it, by checking the type field.

Then I wanted to create another type that will have all the fields from the first union type, but the value field would be optional (can be undefined). Unfortunately this type does not behave in a way I want.

Here is a simplified version of my code to demonstrate the problem:

```
type First = {
  type: 'FIRST';
  value: number;
  uniqueFieldInFirst: string;
};

type Second = {
  type: 'SECOND';
  value: string;
  uniqueFieldInSecond: string;
};

type FirstOrSecond = First | Second;

type Opt<T extends FirstOrSecond>
  = Omit<T, 'value'> // This way we add all fields from FirstOrSecond type expect the 'value'
  & Partial<T>; // And now we all remaining fields (only value, but with "?")

const example: Opt<First> = {
  type: 'FIRST',
  value: 1234,
  uniqueFieldInFirst: 'abc'
}; // works

const another: Opt<Second> = {
  type: 'SECOND',
  value: '1234',
  uniqueFieldInSecond: 'abc'
}; // works

const oneMore: Opt<Second> = {
  type: 'SECOND',
  value: undefined,
  uniqueFieldInSecond: 'abc'
}; // works

const secondTest = (optional: Opt<FirstOrSecond>) => {
  if (optional.value !== undefined) {
    const firstOrSecond: FirstOrSecond = optional;
    // here comes the error:
    // TS2322: Type 'Opt<FirstOrSecond>' is not assignable to type 'FirstOrSecond'.
    // Type 'Omit<FirstOrSecond, "value"> & Partial<First>' is not assignable to type 'FirstOrSecond'.
    // Type 'Omit<FirstOrSecond, "value"> & Partial<First>' is not assignable to type 'First'.
    // Types of property 'value' are incompatible.
    // Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    // Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  }
};
```

My goal is to create working function like this:

```
function mapToFirstOrSecond<T extends FirstOrSecond>(optional: Opt<T>): T | undefined {
  if (optional.value !== undefined) {
    return optional as T;
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

But it doesn't work without casting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a user-defined type guard to make sure the Typescript compiler uses the correct type:

```js
function isFirstOrSecond(optional: any): optional is FirstOrSecond {
    return optional.value !== undefined;
}
```

And then:

```js
if (isFirstOrSecond(optional)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I've heard about. But with this solution I'd have to take responsibility for correct check. This is a little bit similar to casting.
I would be glad if there is a more automated solution to trick the typescript compiler to infer type correctly. Nevertheless, thank you for the answer

Comment: You're taking responsability for the check when you do `if (optional.value !== undefined)`, but the compiler isn't smart enough to infer that a defined value is enough for implicitly casting `Opt<T>` to `T`. The guard just moves the check into a single function and make sure the compiler uses the right type.